# Where do I find field length limits for the Google AdWords API?

Tags: api, xml-documentation, google-ads-api

I am having to use the Google AdWords API for a project, I have large chunks working but I am getting frustrated with the documentation. For example I know that a TextAd headline field has a limit of 25 characters and can't have things like ! and ? in it. The documentation makes no mention of it though:
http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/v200909/AdGroupAdService.TextAd.html

Does anyone know where I can find this kind of info? This is not a question about the TextAd service, but about the documentation so that I don't have to find the limits of all these fields by trial and error.

Many thanks,
b.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old, but since it showed up at the top of my Google search results I though it might be worth posting a link to the limits.

A list of the limits can be found here:

https://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/limits.html

And I found a list of disallowed symbols here (though there might be a better source):

https://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53539

Phil

Answer (score 0):

You won't find these limits in the AdWords API documentation anywhere, because these limitations are imposed by AdWords policies rather than any sort of character limit in the API.

Therefore, you must resort to AdWords documentation in order to find out things like the maximum length for an ad description or headline.

https://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&query=characters&answer=6095&type=f should be a good starting point!

Cheers,
Sérgio

Comment: Thanks for the response Sérgio. I had looked through the documentation, but it doesn't mention things like no exclamation marks etc. They do seem to be policy limitations as you say, but there just seems to be no one resource for finding what is and is not allowed; we struggle as we are advertising brands that have these as part of their identity (magazines like "OK!", "Kerrang!", "Which?" etc).